Translate emit intercept in plugin from vuejs 2 to 3
I'm slowly marching a project from vuejs 2 to 3, keeping with the Options API for now. The previous developer created a plugin that intercepted all emits so they could be logged every time an emit was called in a component. I'm uncertain how to translate this to vuejs 3 aside that the first parameter is now an app instance versus Vue. Here is the relevant plugin block:
function plugin (Vue, options = {}) {
  ...
  const emit = Vue.prototype.$emit
  Vue.prototype.$emit = function (...args) {
    const from = this.$vnode ? this.$vnode.tag : 'Event without vnode'
    if (args.length > 1) {
      log.event(`Event "${args[0]}" from ${from}: `, ...args.slice(1))
    } else {
      log.event(`Event "${args[0]}" from ${from}`)
    }
    emit.apply(this, args)
  }
...

My best guess is with defineEmit, but not quite seeing it.

"In Vue 3, it is no longer possible to use these APIs to listen to a component's own emitted events from within a component. There is no migration path for that use case." Link: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api#migration-strategy
